# Spring/Maven project in Eclipse JEE: applicationContext.xml cannot be opened

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, eclipse-jee, runjettyrun

Having received a Spring/Maven project, I:

- Ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on it,
- Loaded it into Eclipse JEE (latest version, called Neon),
- Added the `Dynamic Web Module` facet to it,
- Clicked Run Jetty on it.

PROBLEM: It does not found its own applicationContext.xml even though it is present in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml`.

```
16:58:58.183 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

QUESTION: How can I tell Eclipse JEE where applicationContext.xml is, or otherwise fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*WEB-INF/classes* is a directory created by the Maven war plugin when it builds the war, it should not be a project folder. The Maven war plugin will create it for any war project so it can put compiled classes and resources there that live in your *src/main/java* and *src/main/resources* folders as per the standard Maven conventions.

Similarly, the *WEB-INF/lib* is automatically created by the war plugin and filled with the dependencies of your war module that are not scoped as provided.

So put the file (and any other file you now have in *src/main/webapp/classes*) in the src/main/resources folder of your war module and it should work as expected.

Side note: this is only for the *classes* and *lib* subdirectories; it is perfectly valid to have a WEB-INF folder in your project so you can add files (say: web.xml) that need to go inside WEB-INF there.